# Error when working with NSManagedObjectContext in background thread

Tags: swift, core-data

So I keep getting this error when I save to core data.

**Coredata[21468:13173906] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request:  , ** -_referenceData64 only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSTemporaryObjectID_default _referenceData64]! with userInfo of (null)**

I recently finished a course on core data, the instructor brush a bit on the topic that core data isn't thread safe. So what he suggested is a child/parent context, so that is what I tried doing but kept getting the error from above. This is how my code looks.

```
struct Service {
static let shared = Service()

func downloadPokemonsFromServer(completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    let urlString = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=9"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Unable to fetch pokemon", err)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateContext.parent = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        do {
            let pokemonJSON = try decoder.decode(PokemonsJSON.self, from: data)
            pokemonJSON.pokemons.forEach { (JSONPokemon) in
                //Works fine with privateContext here
               let pokemon = Pokemon(context: privateContext)
                pokemon.name = JSONPokemon.name
                pokemon.url = JSONPokemon.detailUrl
            }

            //Why does the privateContext work here
            //and doesn't crash my app.
            try privateContext.save()
            try privateContext.parent?.save()
            completion()
        } catch let err {
            print("Unable to decode PokemonJSON. Error: ",err)
            completion()
        }
    }.resume()
}

func fetchMoreDetails(pokemon: Pokemon, urlString: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext, completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Unable to get more details for pokemon", err)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateContext.parent = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        do {
            let pokemonDetailJSON = try decoder.decode(PokemonDetailJSON.self, from: data)
            pokemonDetailJSON.types.forEach { (nestedType) in
                // I can just change this to context and it works
                // Why doesnt it work with privateContext and crashes my app

                let type = Type(context: privateContext)
                type.name = nestedType.type.name

                pokemon.addToTypes(type)
            }

            try privateContext.save()
            try privateContext.parent?.save()

            completion()
        } catch let err {
            print("Unable to decode pokemon more details", err)
            completion()
        }

    }.resume()
}
}
```

So in the downloadPokemonsFromSever, I make a call to an api that parse the json and saves it into Coredata. I followed my instructor instructions, by creating a privateContext and then setting its parent to my mainContext. Then I create a new Pokemon that has a name & url using my privateContext and NOT my mainContext. When I completely parse my Pokemon I go into another api that has more details on that Pokemon.

This is where my app starts to crash. As you can see from the fetchMoreDetails there is a parameter that is context. When I try to create a new Type with privateContext it crashes my app. When I use the context that is passed through it works fine. I would like to know why privateContext works inside downloadPokemonFromServer and not in fetchMoreDetails. I left a comment above the line that I think that crashes my app. This is how I call it in my ViewController, using this action.

```
@objc func handleRefresh() {

    Service.shared.downloadPokemonsFromServer {
        let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
        self.pokemonController.fetchedObjects?.forEach({ (pokemon) in

            Service.shared.fetchMoreDetails(pokemon: pokemon, urlString: pokemon.url ?? "", context: context) {

            }
        })
    }
    tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```